# Excel Condition

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have column A with some numbers and column B, where some cells are empty and some cells contains '+'. And I want to sum cells from Column A, but only cells in rows where B column contains '+'.

For example:

```
A    B
1    +
2    
3    +
4
```

So I want to sum 1 and 3 and get 4.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Define "summarize" please.

Comment: Get sum. 1 + 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUMIF should do it, as in:

`=sumif(B1:B4,"+",A1:A4)`

Answer (score 1):

Here ya go:

```
=SUMIF(B1:B4,"+",A1:A4)
```